# Complex SQL View with Joins & Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

My SQL skill level is pretty basic.  I have certainly written some general queries and done some very generic views.  But once we get into joins, I am choking to get the results that I want, in the view I am creating.

I feel like I am almost there.  Just can't get the final piece

```
SELECT dbo.ics_supplies.supplies_id,
       dbo.ics_supplies.old_itemid,
       dbo.ics_supplies.itemdescription,
       dbo.ics_supplies.onhand,
       dbo.ics_supplies.reorderlevel,
       dbo.ics_supplies.reorderamt,
       dbo.ics_supplies.unitmeasure,
       dbo.ics_supplies.supplylocation,
       dbo.ics_supplies.invtype,
       dbo.ics_supplies.discontinued,
       dbo.ics_supplies.supply,
       dbo.ics_transactions.requsitionnumber,
       dbo.ics_transactions.openclosed,
       dbo.ics_transactions.transtype,
       dbo.ics_transactions.originaldate
FROM   dbo.ics_supplies
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ics_orders
                    ON dbo.ics_supplies.supplies_id = dbo.ics_orders.suppliesid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ics_transactions
                    ON dbo.ics_orders.requisitionnumber =
                       dbo.ics_transactions.requsitionnumber
WHERE  ( dbo.ics_transactions.transtype = 'PO' )
```

When I don't include the WHERE clause, I get 17,000+ records in my view.  That is not correct.  It's doing this because we are matching on a 1 to many table.  Supplies table is 12,000 records.  There should always be 12,000 records. Never more. Never less.

The pieces that I am missing are:

1. I only need ONE matching record from the ICS_Transactions Table.  Ideally, the one that I want is the most current 'ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate'.
2. I only want the ICS_Transactions Table fields to populate IF ICS_Transacions.Type = 'PO'.  Otherwise, these fields should remain null.

Sample code or anything would help a lot.  I have done a lot of research on joins and it's still very confusing to get what I need for results.

EDIT/Update

I feel as if I asked my question in the wrong way, or didn't give a good overall view of what I am asking.  For that, I apologize.  I am still very new to SQL, but trying hard.

ICS_Supplies Table has 12,810 records
ICS_Orders Table has 3,666 records
ICS_Transaction Table has 4,701 records

In short, I expect to see a result of 12,810 records.  No more and no less.  I am trying to create a View of ALL records from the ICS_Supplies table.

Not all records in Supply Table are in Orders and or Transaction Table. But still, I want to see all 12,810 records, regardless.

My users have requested that IF any of these supplies have an open PO (ICS_Transactions.OpenClosed = 'Open' and ICS_Transactions.InvType = 'PO') Then, I also want to see additional fields from ICS_Transactions (ICS_Transactions.OpenClosed, ICS_Transactions.InvType, ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate, ICS_Transactions.RequsitionNumber).

If there are no open PO's for supply record, then these additional fields should be blank/null (regardless to what data is in these added fields, they should display null if they don't meet the criteria).

The ICS_Orders Table is nly needed to hop from the ICS_Supplies to the ICS_Transactions (I first, need to obtain the Requisition Number from the Orders field, if there is one).

I am sorry if I am not doing a good job to explain this.  Please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes that LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move it to the ON clause if you want true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: I tried to do:  Left Outer Join dbo.ics_transactions ON dbo.ics_transactions.requisitionnumber = dbo.ics_orders.requisitionnumber AND dbo.ics_transactions.traanstype = 'PO' but that still brings back 17k + records.

Comment: What is the primary key in the ICS_Transaction table?  I would assume there is an auto-increment "ID" column.  In addition, can it assume that the transaction date would follow the natural order of items added to the table?  ie: you would not have an ID = 1234 with a date 10/2 come after and ID 1235 with a date 9/27.  They would be in natural sequential ID order with the date it was added?

Comment: @drapp Never use a surrogate key in that way. While usual behaviour is that it would be sequentially allocated, such behaviour is not guaranteed. Not to mention the human factor; identity inserts, updates to primary key values, etc. ***Always*** use the datetime column(s) to establish datetime order.

Comment: @MatBailie, I agree, but not seeing the final table structure, knowing the context of any date/time added vs such an order date, in this scenario, I would rely on an auto-increment.  Again, lack of full scope of information only.

Comment: @drapp - regardless of structure, what you are suggesting is bad practice, has multitude failure scenarios, and doing so against advice would get you removed from any of my teams. It is straight out incorrect, and unsupported by all vendors.

Comment: @MatBailie, so be it. If I was on your team and knew all the underlying factors, I WOULD use the damn date/time fields.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of Ross Bush's answer *(It removes a join from the CTE to keep things more focussed, speed things up, and cut down the code)*.

```
;WITH
  ordered_ics_transactions AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY requisitionnumber
                           ORDER BY originaldate DESC
                      )
                        AS seq_id
  FROM
    dbo.ics_transactions
)
SELECT
  s.supplies_id,      s.old_itemid,
  s.itemdescription,  s.onhand,
  s.reorderlevel,     s.reorderamt,
  s.unitmeasure,      s.supplylocation,
  s.invtype,          s.discontinued,
  s.supply,
  t.requsitionnumber, t.openclosed,
  t.transtype,        t.originaldate
FROM
  dbo.ics_supplies           AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  dbo.ics_orders             AS o
    ON  o.supplies_id = s.suppliesid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  ordered_ics_transactions   AS t
    ON  t.requisitionnumber = o.requisitionnumber
    AND t.transtype         = 'PO'
    AND t.seq_id            = 1
```

This will only join the most recent transaction record for each `requisitionnumber`, and only if it has `transtype = 'PO'`

IF you want to reverse that *(joining only transaction records that have `transtype = 'PO'`, and of those only the most recent one)*, then move the `transtype = 'PO'` filter to be a `WHERE` clause inside the `ordered_ics_transactions` CTE.

Comment: MatBailie - Thank you for posting this.  I am trying to step through it, on my end.  But I am getting an error on execution "Invalid Object Name ordered_ics_transactions.  Not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @execchef - There's a typo. In the CTE it's transaction (singular) and in the query its transactions (plural). Will edit now.  *(Most conventions have it that tables are named in the Singular. So, I accidentally named my CTE in the singular. I've edited to use your convention of plural, though I would consider that an error in your naming convention.)*

Comment: That was my naming convention error, and the change works now. Thank you for explaining that to me.  It makes logical sense.  AS is, it brings back 17,305 rows.  Which doesn't make sense.  Of course, I am thinking that perhaps I am not asking my question correctly, as SQL is new for me.  But we are on the right track.   I have a table of supplies 12,000 records.  I want to see ALL 12,000 records in ICS_Supplies.  Within that record set, I want to see if any have an open PO and if so, what date it was created.  I am not sure why I am seeing 5,000 more records in my results.

Comment: I have updated my original question, and added more information under the EDIT area towards the bottom of my original post.  Maybe I am making this over complicated before?

Comment: @execchef In that case you First join is causing the duplication. So, where you have more than one order for any given supply record, you have to decide which order record you want, or use aggregation to collapse multiple records down to one.

Comment: Okay.  Understood.  Moving forward, I am trying to add a WHERE clause on the first join.  (WHERE o.UnitsDelivered is null), as this will only grab records that are open and not yet filled.  That's about the only thing I can use without redesigning the table (which may be the right thing to do long term).  I tried placing the where clause on the first join, both before and after the on statement (ON  o.suppliesID = s.Supplies_ID) - but I get errors both ways.  Where exactly should  I place that clause ?

Comment: @execchef Debugging in comments is no possible. Open a new question with full information (query, example data, error messages, etc) on the new situation.  (Enough information that we can replicate your circumstances on dbfiddle.uk for example)

Comment: Thank you for all of your time here.  I really appreciate it.  I took your advice.  Walked away, cleared my head and then posted the question in a manner that made better sense.  And I believe it is now resolved.  Thanks again!!!!!

Comment: @execchef it's been answered and accepted, good news :)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly work with the query below to get what you need.

*1. I only need ONE matching record from the ICS_Transactions Table. Ideally, the one that I want is the most current 'ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate'.*

I would solve this by creating a CTE with all the ICS_Transaction fields needed in the query, rank-ordered by OPriginalDate, partitioned by suppliesid.

*2. I only want the ICS_Transactions Table fields to populate IF ICS_Transacions.Type = 'PO'. Otherwise, these fields should remain null.*

If you move the condition from the WHERE clause to the LEFT JOIN then ICS_Transactions not matching the criteria will be peeled and replaced with null values with the rest of the query records.

```
;
WITH ReqNumberRanked AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.ICS_Orders.SuppliesID,
        dbo.ICS_Transactions.RequisitionNumber,
        dbo.ICS_Transactions.TransType,
        dbo.ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate,
        dbo.ICS_Transactions.OpenClosed, 
        RequisitionNumberRankReversed = RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY dbo.ICS_Orders.SuppliesID, dbo.ICS_Transactions.RequisitionNumber ORDER BY dbo.ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate DESC)  
    FROM
        dbo.ICS_Orders
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ICS_Transactions ON dbo.ICS_Orders.RequisitionNumber = dbo.ICS_Transactions.RequsitionNumber
)
SELECT        
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.Supplies_ID, dbo.ICS_Supplies.Old_ItemID, 
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.ItemDescription, dbo.ICS_Supplies.OnHand, 
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.ReorderLevel, dbo.ICS_Supplies.ReorderAmt, 
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.UnitMeasure, 
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.SupplyLocation, dbo.ICS_Supplies.InvType, 
    dbo.ICS_Supplies.Discontinued, dbo.ICS_Supplies.Supply, 
    ReqNumberRanked.RequsitionNumber, 
    ReqNumberRanked.OpenClosed, 
    ReqNumberRanked.TransType, 
    ReqNumberRanked.OriginalDate
FROM            
    dbo.ICS_Supplies 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ICS_Orders ON dbo.ICS_Supplies.Supplies_ID = dbo.ICS_Orders.SuppliesID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ReqNumberRanked ON ReqNumberRanked.RequisitionNumber = dbo.ICS_Transactions.RequsitionNumber 
        AND (ReqNumberRanked.TransType = 'PO') 
        AND ReqNumberRanked.RequisitionNumberRankReversed = 1
```

Comment: I have never used Partition By before and therefore I don't have much insight.  I am getting the following error: Error in list of function arguments: 'PARTITION' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: Doh! That is because I had a typo. It has been fixed. The syntax is RANK() OVER(<PARTITION BY X> ORDER BY Y)

Comment: The partition in rank specifies the cluster or groupings for the ranking, in your case I think that is supplier and then requisition Number. That means for each supplier, the requisition numbers will be ranked in the order specified by in the order by field, which original date seems to be a good candidate. This will allow duplicate supplier/ requisition numbers to contribute to the rank. Since those values are in reverse order, taking the first record of each partition will be the last existing record by supplier and requisition number.

Comment: `Rank=1` needs to be in the `LEFT JOIN` predicate too *(the current position turns everything in to `INNER` joins)*.  It should be made clear that this can still cause duplicates if multiple entries have the same date *(and that `ROW_NUMBER()` can address that, though may may arbitrary non-deterministic choices)*.  And there's no point joining the `Orders` in the CTE ***and*** outside of it, you only need it joining once.

Comment: @MatBailie - I am flying blind and hashing this out in my head (no sample data). This is correct, the rank=1 in the where would make it an inner join. I moved it to the left join clause.