# Complex SQL Joins with Where Clauses

Tags: sql, subquery, left-join, inner-join

Being pretty new to SQL, I ask for your patience. I have been banging my head trying to figure out how to create this VIEW by joining 3 tables.  I am going to use mock tables, etc to keep this very simple.  So that I can try to understand the answer - no just copy and paste.

ICS_Supplies:

```
    Supplies_ ID      Item_Description
    -------------------------------------
     1            |     PaperClips
     2            |     Rubber Bands
     3            |     Stamps
     4            |     Staples
```

ICS_Orders:

```
    ID         SuppliesID            RequisitionNumber
    ----------------------------------------------------
    1    |      1             |        R1234a
    6    |      4             |        R1234a
    2    |      1             |        P2345b
    3    |      2             |        P3456c
    4    |      3             |        R4567d
    5    |      4             |        P5678e
```

ICS_Transactions:

```
    ID    RequsitionNumber      OrigDate      TransType    OpenClosed
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    1    |  R1234a        |     06/12/20   |    Req      |    Open
    2    |  P2345b        |     07/09/20   |    PO       |    Open
    3    |  P3456c        |     07/14/20   |    PO       |    Closed
    4    |  R4567d        |     08/22/20   |    Req      |    Open
    5    |  P5678e        |     11/11/20   |    PO       |    Open
```

And this is what I want to see in my View Results

```
    Supplies_ID    Item             RequsitionNumber  OriginalDate  TransType  OpenClosed
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1       |   Paper Clips   |   P2345b         |    07/09/20   |  PO     |  OPEN
       2       |   Rubber Bands  |   Null           |     Null      |  Null   |  Null
       3       |   Stamps        |   Null           |     Null      |  Null   |  Null
       4       |   Staples       |   P56783         |    11/11/20   |  PO     |  OPEN
```

I just can't get there.  I want to always have the same amount of records that we have in the ICS_Supplies Table.  I need to join to the ICS_Orders Table in order to grab the Requisition Number because that's what I need to join on the ICS_Transactions Table.  I don't want to see data in the new added fields UNLESS ICS_Transactions.TransType = 'PO' AND ICS_Transactions.OpenClosed = 'OPEN', otherwise the joined fields should be seen as null, regardless to what they contain.  IF that is possible?

My research shows this is probably a LEFT Join, which is very new to me.  I had made many attempts on my own, and then posted my question yesterday.  But I was struggling to ask the correct question and it was recommended by other members that I post the question again . .

If needed, I can share what I have done, but I fear it will make things overly confusing as I was going in the wrong direction.

I am adding a link to the original question, for those that need some background info

[Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775420/complex-sql-view-with-joins-where-clause/64778184?noredirect=1#comment114678509_64778184)

If there is any additional information needed, just ask.  I do apologize in advance if I have left out any needed details.

Comment: Show us your LEFT JOIN attempt.

Comment: @jarlh - I didn't post it because, I had shared a link with my original question, and my original left join and all the work I had done previously.  I didn't feel it to be good practice to duplicate all of that over here. Instead, I shared a link - just like my post says.  Regardless, it's answered now, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, because you want to exclude rows in the second table depending on whether there is a match in the third table - so two `left join`s are not what you are after.

I think this implements the logic you want:

```
select s.supplies_id, s.item_description,
    t.requisition_number, t.original_date, t.trans_type, t.open_closed
from ics_supplies s
left join ics_transaction t
    on  t.transtype = 'PO' 
    and t.open_closed = 'Open'
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from ics_order o 
        where o.supplies_id = s.supplies_id and o.requisition_number = t.requisition_number
    )
```

Another way to phrase this would be an `inner join` in a subquery, then a `left join`:

```
select s.supplies_id, s.item_description,
    t.requisition_number, t.original_date, t.trans_type, t.open_closed
from ics_supplies s
left join (
    select o.supplies_id, t.*
    from ics_order o
    inner join ics_transaction t 
        on t.requisition_number = o.requisition_number
    where t.transtype = 'PO' and t.open_closed = 'Open'
) t on t.supplies_id = s.supplies_id
```

Comment: thank you for posting this response.  The logic in the first example was easy to understand (for a newbie), and it brings back the results that I expect.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This query should return the data for supplies.  The left join will add in all orders that have a supply_id (and return null for the orders that don't).

```
select
    s.supplies_id
    ,s.Item_Description as [Item]
    ,t.RequisitionNumber
    ,t.OrigDate as [OriginalDate]
    ,t.TransType
    ,t.OpenClosed
from ICS_Supplies s
    left join ICS_Orders o on o.supplies_id = s.supplies_id
    left join ICS_Transactions t on t.RequisitionNumber = o.RequisitionNumber
where t.TransType = 'PO'
    and t.OpenClosed = 'Open'
```

The null values will automatically show null if the record doesn't exist.  For example, you are joining to the Transactions table and if there isn't a transaction_id for that supply then it will return 'null'.

Modify your query, run it, then maybe update your question using real examples if it's possible.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is applied After the join, at which point NULLs fail the condition, become excluded, and turn the OUTER joins in to INNER joins.

Answer (score 1):

In the original question you wrote:

> "I only need ONE matching record from the ICS_Transactions Table.
> Ideally, the one that I want is the most current
> 'ICS_Transactions.OriginalDate'."

So the goal is to get the most recent transaction for which the TransType is 'PO' and OpenClosed is 'Open'.  That the purpose of the CTE 'oa_cte' in this code.  The appropriate transactions are then LEFT JOIN'ed on SuppliesId.  Something like this

```
with oa_cte(SuppliesId, RequsitionNumber, OriginalDate,
            TransType, OpenClosed, RowNum) as (
    select o.SuppliesId, o.RequsitionNumber, 
           t.OrigDate, t.TransType, t.OpenClosed, 
           row_number() over (partition by o.SuppliesId
                              order by t.OrigDate desc) 
    from ICS_Orders o
         join ICS_Transactions t on o.RequisitionNumber=t.RequisitionNumber
    where t.TransType='PO' 
          and t.OpenClosed='OPEN')
select s.*, oa.*
from ICS_Supplies s
     left join oa_cte oa on s.SuppliesId=oa.SuppliesId
                            and oa.RowNum=1;
```

Comment: Yes  You are correct.  One thing that has come to my knowledge between posting the original question and now, was that I have learned that there are never two open PO's for the same supply item, simultaneously.  Therefore. . . I may have been erroneously making things more complicated than need be.  I may implement this regardless, at some point, to protect the integrity of the view . . . as the application changes over time.  This is an old app that was created 20 years ago, and the tables have misspellings and bad practice.  I need to invest some time to clean it up and safeguard